# Problema al deshacer la creación de un evento

Tags: visual-studio, .net

A menudo al crear un form por casualidad creo un evento al hacer click en un label.
Intento deshacer los cambios con Ctrl + Z o borrar el código del evento, pero me muestra una advertencia y al volver al form todo lo que he agregado desaparece.
Como puedo evitar este problema y regresar al momento antes de crear el evento?

```
namespace Ahorros
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es porque tu evento, no solo se creo ahi, si no que tambien se creo en la lista de eventos del objeto.. debes eliminarlo de ahi (en la barra de herramientas del objeto ves sus eventos tambien).. si no.. tambien podes abrir el form.designer y borrarlo manualmente de ahi....

Comment: Y para la proxima, recuerda, el codigo como texto...

Comment: Cuando crees un evento sobre un componente y quieras borrarlo, tambien tenes la opciones en las  propiedades de ese componente, elegis el  rayo y ahi  estan todos los  eventos  disponibles y creados  sobre ese componente en particular y lo podes borrar desde ahi.